# How to duplicate a VHD with Windows 7 so others can use it?

Tags: windows, vhd, sysprep

I have created a VHD image with Windows 7, Visual Studio 2010 and a couple of SDKs, which took a while to install. Now I want to share this VHD with my coleagues so they don't have to go through the whole installation process themselves. How should I go about sysprepping it?

Note that we are all using Hyper-V on Windows Server 8 (each of us has its own server) to host our VMs.

I found a couple of blogs on AIK but nothing to point.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sysprep /generalize /oobe` and then give the VHD to your colleagues.